# How do I check if an IsolatedStorageFile exists?

Tags: .net, isolatedstorage

We have code like:

```
try  
{   
   streamOptions = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(  “FileName”,  
                                                    FileMode.Open,  
                                                    FileAccess.Read);  
}  
catch ( FileNotFoundException )  
{  
   this.userSettings = new UserSettings();  
   load = false;  
}
```

This make Visual Studio break into the debugger often when I am debugging, therefore I wish to protect the above code with a “if”, so it only runs when the IsolatedStorageFile exists.  However it is not clear how to use IsolatedStorageFile.FileExists() to check for the **file that IsolatedStorageFileStream is about to open**, e.g. what options do I have to give when I "new" a IsolatedStorageFile object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private bool IsolatedStorageFileExists(string name)
{
  using (var folder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain())
  {
    return folder.FileExists(name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [FileExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.fileexists.aspx) method on the [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76z57x8.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (store.FileExists(your_file_name)) { do something if file exist }
                    else { do something if file not exist}
            }
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You'll probably get a lot more upvotes that way!